# Can't renounce my citizenship due to being a deserter; can I apply for German citizenship?

Tags: germany, military

I'm a Turkish citizen who is studying in Germany for the last 5 years. As one might not know, in Turkey, there is compulsory military service for every men. But, I don't want to do it (I don't want to be physically present on Turkish soil). There is also the option of paying ~€6000 and just doing your military service for 3weeks, but I don't want to do it either; I don't have that much money for that kind of thing.

Now, I want to become a German citizen by naturalisation, but Germany doesn't allow me to have dual citizenship *unless I have no other options*.

To do that, I want to renounce my Turkish citizenship but the government will be asking me to do my military service in a couple of months and I have no other excuse to give them, so I'll be a deserter, and the Turkish government doesn't allow anyone to renounce their citizenship if they deserted from their military service. So, long story short, there is no way I can renounce my Turkish citizenship.

**My question is**, in 3 years, I'll be able to apply for a German citizenship but I won't be be able to renounce my Turkish citizenship (due to being a deserter). Will the German government recognise my situation and allow me to apply for German citizenship? Have there been similar cases before? If so, what was their result?

Note that, *criminals* are not allowed to apply for a German citizenship, so I don't know whether the German government would consider being a deserter as a being criminal.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to move to expatriates.stackexchange.com which is much more specialised in questions of citizenship .

Comment: That said, you are obviously free to denounce your citizenship and Turkey is free not to accept it, but for Germany _your_ action might be enough.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think the question is well suited for this site, as it specifically asks for how the German sees this situations.

Comment: @gnasher729 can you, formally, prove that you denounced your citizenship (regardless of whether the your country accepts it or not)?

Comment: I would assume that the Turkish government or their embassy would reply with a letter like “we received your letter about denouncing your Turkish citizenship and reject it”. If they just throw your letter in the bin, you’d probably go to a Notar who will witness that you sent your letter. Worst case that Notar would walk with you to a Turkish embassy and witness them rejecting your letter - for an appropriate fee. He’ll file it under “stories to tell my grandchildren”.

Comment: No, I don’t know exactly how to do it, but there will be ways. And you don’t need to convince the Turkish side but the German side.

Comment: This is a law site, not a German/Turkish law site. Expatriates is about immigration, citizenship etc. Much more specialised for this subject.

Comment: @gnasher729 German and Turkish law are both law.  This site has countless questions restricted to certain jurisdictions.  Indeed, if such questions were forbidden the site probably wouldn't be viable. This question is on topic for both sites.  Answers here will tend to be restricted to the legal analysis, while answer at [Expatriates.SE] may include more information about practical matters, if any such information may be helpful.

Comment: I expect that this situation has been encountered before by the German authorities, who probably have a well defined policy or even a judicial determination about whether someone in your situation "has no other option" for the purpose of German law, or establishing a course of action that does not require you to join the Turkish military.

Comment: For 2nd, 3rd generation Turks, court rulings have allowed these exceptions (Military service deemed unreasonable): [2010-10-26: Einbürgerung ohne türkischen Militärdienst | Rechtslupe](https://www.rechtslupe.de/verwaltungsrecht/einbuergerung-ohne-tuerkischen-militaerdienst-323738). As a **native born** (which I assume you are), this might not be the case. You should make an appointment **now** and ask for an assessment for a future application under these conditions.

Comment: @phoog I don’t quite get your attitude. This is a highly specialised law question where on expatriates it’s much more a run of the mill question, and more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: For something this serious, you should not rely on a website (research is good though). IMHO, you would be well advised to do your research and immediately hire a local German attorney that specializes in immigration.

Comment: The question is certainly on-topic here. It might also be on-topic on Expatriates too, in which case asking the question there as well would be appropriate. If you do this then please link the questions.

Comment: I just want to point out the extreme risk of having to be in a country without citizenship.  The EU could eject you for a number of reasons prior to approval of citizenship, and your result would be prison in Turkey.

Answer (score 3):

> Note that, criminals are not allowed to apply for a German citizenship, so I don't know whether the German government would consider being a deserter as a being criminal.

First of all, they would deny a criminal German citizenry, but that goes only for crimes, that are also illegal in Germany ([Sec. 12a § 2 Nationality Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stag/englisch_stag.html#p0089), [§ 12a Abs. 2 StAG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stag/__12a.html)). Were you - for instance - convicted for muder you couldn't become a German citizen. Desertion in that sense however is not a criminal offence in Germany, so you're good.

Regarding double citizenship, [Sec. 12 § 1 2nd sentence no. 2 Nationality Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stag/englisch_stag.html#p0079) ([§ 12 Abs. 1 S. 2 Nr. 2 StAG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stag/__12.html)) allows you to keep your original citizenship, if the country of origin "regularly refuses to grant release from citizenship", which should be the case here. Therefore, you could become a German citizen according to [Sec. 10 Nationality Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stag/englisch_stag.html#p0054) ([§ 10 StAG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stag/__10.html)).